# PowerShell Sending Echo output to Email

Tags: powershell

Hi guys I'm trying to send output of echo command on log file as body of a email by using Send-MailMessage.

Now I am able to send log file only, but I wish to send content of that log in body of a email.

How to manage that?

Currently I'm using this line:

```
Send-MailMessage -from donotreply@company.com -to "nobody@company.com" -subject "test" -body "test" -Attachment "C:\log.log" -smtpServer smtp.Server.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the contents of the log file and use that for the Body parameter

```
# -Raw reads it as single multiline string, including newlines
$body = Get-Content -Path 'C:\log.log' -Raw  
Send-MailMessage -Body $body ...
```

If the mail is to be HTML (with switch `-BodyAsHtml`), you need to convert the newlines to `<br />` like

```
# without -Raw you get the content as string array
$body = (Get-Content -Path 'C:\log.log') -join '<br />'
Send-MailMessage -Body $body -BodyAsHtml ...
```

Comment: That do a trick, so now im facing new problem :) I want to schedule this script in Task Scheduler and for no it doesnt work. It nahgs in status running and i end it every time. Aby suggestions maybe?

Comment: @user3391373 That could be caused by a number of reasons like a permissions problem on the user running the task to access the log file. Please post a new question for this and explain the problem and the errors you see (if any)